# excel macro pass data between two forms where focus is set

Tags: excel, vba

I have two forms.
`form1` has four text boxes and a button for each textbox.
The button would setfocus on the textbox and bring up `form2`.
`form2` is basicly a number keypad that also has a text box so that the user can select a number. That number will go in `form2.textbox`, which when changed will put the data in `form1.textbox1`.

The problem I'm having is how to tell `form2.textbox` to put data in `form1.textbox2`.

This is what my code looks like:

```
Public Sub textbox1_Click()
    Me.textbox1.SetFocus
    numbfrm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_Click()
    Me.textbox2.SetFocus
    numbfrm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub textbox3_Click()
    Me.txtactual.SetFocus
    numbfrm.Show
End Sub
```

This is what is in the number form. It contains all of the numbers 1 to 10, but I just put the first three numbers here.

```
Private Sub Cmd1_Click()
    TxtNumber.Value = TxtNumber.Value & "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd2_Click()
    TxtNumber.Value = TxtNumber.Value & "2"
End Sub

Public Sub TxtNumber_Change()
    passnumber
End Sub
```

This is in a module:

```
Sub passnumber()
    form1.textbox1.Value = numbfrm.TxtNumber
End Sub
```

I've been looking through the web to find an easy way to do that.
I tried puting in the module

```
Sub passnumber()
    If form1.texbox1.foucs =true then
        form1.textbox1.Value = numbfrm.TxtNumber
    Else If form1.textbox2.foucs = true then
        form1.texbox2.value =numbfrm.txtnumber
End sub
```

Comment: Sorry! :) Will do that next time.Thanks for the edits :)

Comment: Why you cannot use directly from UserForm1 the code UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text  ? If you have a dedicated button to SetFocus, put inside the code to fill the TextBox... Otherwise use a public var to fill and recall in the UserForm2.

Comment: I cant use it directly cause the number form puts the data in txtNumber.value. We would have to create form for each text box value

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround for it, I put toggle buttons next to each box and when button is pressed it would mark it as true, and then I told it if that toggle is true it would use certain text box

```
Sub passnumber()
    If form1.option1.value =true then
    form1.textbox1.Value = numbfrm.TxtNumber 
else 
    If form1.option2.value =true then
    form1.textbox2.Value = numbfrm.TxtNumber
    end if
    end if
End sub
```